# Excel: Find cell which is duplicate if another column cell is duplicate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to locate rows which contain duplicates based on two columns. It is a little hard to explain but let me try. Below is a picture on what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example Image]

If an ID value (Column B) has a duplicate and the values in the IDF's (Column C) are different it needs to highlight the column or in Column D provide some text which I can use for conditional formatting.

**Scenario's**

1. Rows 5-7 have the same ID but there is a different IDF value in one of the fields, therefore it needs to be highlighted
2. Rows 9-10 have the same ID and all of the IDF values are the same, no further action is needed
3. Rows 11-15 have the same ID but there is different IDF values so all of the rows relating to that ID need to be highlighted
4. Row 3 has only one ID value row therefore no further action is required

This is a little hard to explain, but please. Let me know if it makes sense or if you need any more information.

**Also Note:** This data will be sorted by ID (unlike the example shown above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quickly with a PivotTable. Click anywhere in your table and then click **Insert > PivotTable** from the menu bar.

Add **ID** and **IDF** to the Rows area of the PivotTable. It will look something like this:

[image]

Now, click anywhere on the PivotTable and select **Design > Report Layout > Show In Tabular Form**. Right-click any of the cells that say something like **1 Total** and untick **Subtotal ID**.

It will look like this, with gaps where you have multiple IDFs per ID.

[image]

Right-click any value in the ID column, and select **Field Settings**. On the **Layout & Print** tab, tick **Repeat item labels**.

In column D of your original table, in the first data row - add this formula, making sure to change **I2:I20** to wherever you have put the first column of your PivotTable.

For each ID, it counts how many distinct IDFs there are, and will output **flag** if there are more than 1. You can use this to drive conditional formatting.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I2:I20,B3)=1,"","Flag")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer with a great explanation! Thanks you so much